# Replace all newlines between "two lines with certain patterns" with a comma in vim

Tags: regex, vim, newline

If I have to replace newlines with comma for all lines between Pattern 1 and Pattern 2, how do I do it?

From:

```
Pattern 1  
abcd
edfgads asd
adsad
...
Pattern 2
```

to:

```
Pattern 1, abcd, edfgads asd, adsad, ..., Pattern 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
:%s/Pattern 1\_.\{-}Pattern 2/\=join(split(submatch(0), "\n"), ", ")/g
```

Search

```
Pattern 1     # obvious
\_.           # any character including newline
\{-}          # repeat non-greedily (vim's way of writing *?)
Pattern 2     # obvious
```

The replace part should be clear without an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Pattern 1` and `Pattern 2` as addresses, see `:help cmdline-ranges`:

```
:/^Pattern 1/,/^Pattern 2/-1 s/\n/, /
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put line number while substituting.

```
:{pattern1LineNo},{pattern2LineNo}s/\n/, /g
```

Comment: Only useful if you know the line numbers and the area in question occurs only once in the file.

Comment: @Tomalak: yes, the OP didn't mention about multiple occurrences. I wanted to make sure he is aware that we can put in range while substituting.

Comment: He did, in the comments

Answer (score 0):

For vim it would be

```
:%s/\n/, /g
```

You search for a newline character: `\n` and replace it with comma and space: `,` which is done globally `g`, these options are split by `/` character.

More info about replace in vim you can find [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

Comment: But, I don't want to replace all newlines with comma. Only certain lines between Pattern 1 and Pattern2. And Pattern1 ... Pattern2 occurs many number of times in the file.

Comment: Oops, sorry, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
:g/Pattern1/norm V/Pattern2^MgJ
```

- `:g/` on lines matching Pattern1, run the `normal` mode keystrokes:

  - `v`isual select as far as... `/`search for Pattern2
  - `gJ` Join selected lines, without adding spaces

  NB. Type the `^M` with `Ctrl-V <Enter>`, or `Ctrl-Q <Enter>`